# How to have no context with a docker compose service?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When building a docker image, we can avoid a context entirely by piping the Dockerfile.

For example:

```
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

Is there a way to emulate this with docker compose when specifying a service?

Answer (score 0):

Not that there is always a context in place when you build an image with docker, having `no context` is not possible. What you mean perhaps is `not having to specify` a context. I mean `context` in a strict sense of `a directory that has your data`.

For this, you can use the `build` directive and provide it the name of a directory which holds a valid `Dockerfile` and it will be used automatically when building the image. Here, the `.` represents the directory that has the `docker-compose.yaml` file.

```
build: ./my-build-dir
```

> Note: This only works when your dockerfile is called `Dockerfile`.

But if you want to specify a Dockerfile with a name other than `Dockerfile` you will have to use a different way. This is done by specifying the Dockerfile and the context. The example below assumes that you have a Dockerfile named `Dockerfile.something` present in your directory that has `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile.something
```